# How to add monit cartridge to OpenShift?

Tags: openshift, openshift-client-tools

I'm trying to add the monit cartridge to my OpenShift app using the following syntax:

```
rhc cartridge add https://github.com/openshift-cartridges/openshift-origin-cartridge-monit/blob/master/metadata/manifest.yml -a <appName> -n <domainName>
```

Unfortunately I'm always getting:

```
The cartridge manifest at <linkFromAbove> could not be downloaded: The
cartridge manifest at <linkFromAbove> must be smaller than 20480 bytes.
```

What's the problem - how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I came across a similar problem now, so I'm leaving the solution here for others who might have the same problem.

If you are adding the cartridge via the webconsole, you need to use the **link for the raw file**, i.e:

`https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openshift-cartridges/openshift-origin-cartridge-monit/master/metadata/manifest.yml`

Answer (score 0):

The cartridge has been updated and should now be working, it was trying to download a version that did not exist anymore.  It is now downloading the latest version.